# pass a reference for one object to another method in another class

Tags: java, class, object, methods

How do you pass an objects reference to another method in another class?

The goal of my program is to calculate the students GPA from a file containing their transcript. There are 3 classes involved for the part I am struggling with.

There is the GPACalculator, which contains main. There is the transcript and course classes. the transcript class reads the file and builds a course out of it.

So far I have the transcript class with a method to read current line of the transcript file and construct a course object out of this information.

I now need to be able to send the course object to the main method of the gpa calculator so i can print it to the terminal window. This is where I am stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPA calculator probably needs to make a new course object:

```
CourseObject courseobject = new CourseObject(args);
```

Then you need to do something like: `courseobject.getData();`

Comment: This answer but all I had to do was create a course with out a reference and have the transcript class pass the reference with a return statement. Thanks! got me thinking in the right direction.